# MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an ajax call on a php page, but the following error appears :

> Le script à l’adresse «
>   http://localhost/Moone/example/public/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js » a
>   été chargé alors que son type MIME (« text/html ») n’est pas un type
>   MIME JavaScript valide.

I tried to manipulate Apache's configuration by adding this to httpd.conf :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

</IfModule>
```

but it gives the same error message

Comment: What do you see when you navigate directly to that file in your browser?

Comment: hi, what do you mean by navigate ?

Comment: Type in your browser's address bar that uri (or even just click the link you posted in the question).

Comment: it says "The requested URL /Moone/chatroulette/1er- vers-fonct-fini/example/public/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js was not found on this server." when i open on the browser